How to properly type a getter when assigning value using a tuple
In my TS React App, I am using Zustand to manage the states of all dialogs/modals.
Here is how I typed the ModalStoreState:
type ModalStoreState = {
   /**
    * 1st arg is "name" of the target dialog, while 2nd arg is "data" corresponding with it.
    * 
    * How should I type "data" in a way that when I create a getter fn, the type will be inferred correctly?
    */
   opened: [string, any][]; 
};

While here is how I typed the ModalStoreActions:
type ModalStoreActions = {
   open: (data: [string, any]) => void;
   close: (name: string) => void;
   /**
    * Here is the getter fn, how do I type this one that it will infer the type of the object provided on open?
    */
   getData: (name: string) => ...
};

export const useModalStore = create<ModalStore>((set, get) => ({
   ...initialState,
   open: (data) => set((state) => ({ opened: state.opened.concat(data) })),
   close: (name) => set((state) => ({ opened: state.opened.filter((x) => x[0] !== name) })),
   getData: (name) => {
      /**
       * This is how I assumed the getter fn, would be implemented. :D
       */
      const opened = get().opened.find((x) => x[0] === name);

      if (!opened) {
         return null;
      }

      return opened[1];
   },
}));

Is it possible to infer the type of the "data" provided during "open" fn, considering that I should only be able to input either "object" or "null" type?

If you don't get enough engagement here, consider [edit]ing to remove the dependency on zustand and react so the code is a [mre] people can paste into a standalone TypeScript IDE (if you're asking about getters and tuples, you should be able to ask that with just plain TypeScript).

Tangent to the Q: the matched overload signature corresponding to the usage of create shown in the example code is deprecated — it is recommended to use useStore and createStore instead.

Does all data in opened have the same type for the same store? Or do you need to be able to mix types passed into open for the same store?

Hi @JosephStewart the "opened" contains a list of tuple with the 1st arg as "name" and 2nd arg as "data"... In this case "data" could be any object type or null... To answer the question only the "data" attribute will have varying attributes based on what will satisfy the state of the respective modal.

@atlas.code I see. If ‘data’ truly needs to be any so that the ‘opened’ array can hold mixed types, then I don’t think there’s a way for you to infer a return type for ‘getData’ since there’s no way for typescript to statically determine the possible values when the store is created. I think your next best option is probably to change the typing to ‘unknown’ and use type guards

You can leverage TypeScript’s generics and conditional types.
Define a type that ensures the data can only be of type object or null:
type ModalData = object | null;

Use generics to type ModalStoreState and ModalStoreActions.
type ModalStoreState<T extends ModalData> = {
   opened: [string, T][];
};

type ModalStoreActions<T extends ModalData> = {
   open: (data: [string, T]) => void;
   close: (name: string) => void;
   getData: (name: string) => T | null;
};

Finally, apply this generic type when creating the Zustand store:
export const useModalStore = create<ModalStoreState<ModalData> & ModalStoreActions<ModalData>>((set, get) => ({
   opened: [],
   open: (data) => set((state) => ({ opened: state.opened.concat(data) })),
   close: (name) => set((state) => ({ opened: state.opened.filter((x) => x[0] !== name) })),
   getData: (name) => {
      const opened = get().opened.find((x) => x[0] === name);
      return opened ? opened[1] : null;
   },
}));

ModalData restricts the type of data to be either an object or null.
Generics (T) allow the getData to infer the correct type of data based on what was provided to open.
The return type of getData will be inferred correctly as either the type of data or null.

If you want to extract argument of open function, here's how you do that
type ModalStoreActions = {
   open: (data: [string, any]) => void;
   close: (name: string) => void;
   // this is your type from ModalStoreActions => open => data => [any]
   getData: (name: string) => Parameters<ModalStoreActions["open"]>[0][0][1] 
};

Typescript playground
